# Apache Felix: Command not found 'junit'

Tags: java, junit, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I am trying to write sample test cases for OSGI services by following the documentation here; 
http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-junit4osgi/apache-felix-ipojo-junit4osgi-tutorial.html

And test case class and `MANIFEST.MF` are below;

```
package com.rajkishan.osgidemo;

import org.apache.felix.ipojo.junit4osgi.OSGiTestCase;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;

import com.rajkishan.osgidemo.locationtracker.ILocationTracker;

/**
 * Unit test for simple Location Service.
 */
public class ServiceTest extends OSGiTestCase {
// Test Location Tracker Service Availability
public void testLocationTrackerServiceAvailability() {
    ServiceReference reference = context
            .getServiceReference(ILocationTracker.class.getName());
    assertNotNull("Assert Availability", reference);
}

public void testLocationMessage() {
    ServiceReference reference = context
            .getServiceReference(ILocationTracker.class.getName());
    assertNotNull("Assert Availability", reference);
    ILocationTracker service = (ILocationTracker) context
            .getService(reference);
    String message = service.getLocation();
    assertNotNull("Check Message Existance", message);
    assertEquals("Check The Message", "Got location as MyCity", message);
 }
}
```

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1446545137113
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_60
Built-By: Rajkishan_2
Bundle-Activator: com.rajkishan.osgidemo.TestServiceActivator
Bundle-Description: Service To Test How to Run Tests in OSGI Services
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: osgi-test
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.rajkishan.osgidemo.osgi-test
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: com.rajkishan.osgidemo;uses:="org.apache.felix.ipojo.jun
    it4osgi,org.osgi.framework";version="1.0.0"
Import-Package: com.rajkishan.osgidemo.locationtracker;version="[1.0,2)"
    ,org.apache.felix.ipojo.junit4osgi,org.osgi.framework;version="[1.3,2)"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Test-Suite: com.rajkishan.osgidemo.ServiceTest
Tool: Bnd-3.0.0.201509101326
```

But whenever i try the command, `junit {Bundle ID}` it says,

`shell: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: junit`

See the Screenshot below;

[image]

What i am missing here?

**NOTE**: It works fine if i try from Swing-GUI. But not from command prompt.

Comment: I am currently struggling with this problem, too. Were you successful with resolving this issue?

Comment: @aron23 : Sadly... not yet. For now, i am using the Swing-GUI for tests. Did not get enough time to look more into this.